# is there a way to read JSON elements from a file?(without deserializing them)

Tags: c#, json

I have a text file that has several elements in a JSON format 
I can of course read the text file and deserialize it into objects

However I wonder if there is a way to read this and divide it into its elements -even just one level- without deserializing them?

The reason is because I need the elements in JSON format and it seens silly to deserialize it ,divide it and serialize them again

Example:

```
{  "name": "John Smith",
    "address":"Fascination Street #222"
    "number": 5
}
{    "number":5,
     "image":"Qlsdfsdfjsdfksdfksdfjsdfk......",
     "payment": 500
}
{    "number":5,
     "image":"Qlsdfas;fldjkewlfdsdfjsdfksdfksdfjsdfk......",
     "payment": 300
}
....
```

I want to have each of these elements (between the `{ }`s) separatedly.(take into account that inside them there can be other {'s or also arrays []'s)

Answer (score -2):

I think, here there is a way to do that: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

If no, give an example, pls.

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please delete.